# You'll vs You'd

Tags: will-would, would

Which sentence is more correct?

> Look closely, and **you'd** never have guessed it was fake.

or

> Look closely, and **you'll** never have guessed it was fake.

Answer (score 1):

They are both "off". The second is not usable, but the first could be salvaged and improved. E.g.:

> Looking closely, you'd never have guessed it was fake.

That avoids the issue of clashing tenses.

Comment: Do you mean that examining it from a distance would have made things easier? Interesting.

Comment: Alright @Ricky smartypants—"Even looking at it closely, you'd …"

Comment: ... said he whilst applying acrylic paint to a Frans Hals poster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in tense, but not much, and they are both not quite right. In my view, "Look closely, and you'd never have guessed it was fake." for things vaguely in the recent past, is probably the preferred use.

However if you were standing in front of Diplodocus in the British Museum at that very moment, you might say: Look closely, but you'd never guess it was fake." The construction "you'll never have guessed ..." is probably a little unusual (if not to say, never used).